# How I git merge a 2nd time?

Tags: git, merge

I have performed a merge. Later on, more commits were made. Then it was uncovered that the conflict resolution I performed on that merge were wrong. I have since fixed this in older versions, but now I need to merge that old branch again. Unfortunately, git thinks this has been resolved, so it doesn't bring forth any of the changes I want. In a sense, I want to go through the conflict resolution process again, but I can't given that all of this has already been pushed to origin with more changes applied on top.

Answer (score 0):

`git reset --hard ORIG_HEAD`

where `ORIG_HEAD` is the commit right before the merge, assuming you don't mind erasing the history between `ORIG_HEAD` and `HEAD` (answer courtesy of [GitHub](http://help.github.com/git-cheat-sheets/)).